# html anchor tag onclick problems !

Tags: html, anchor

I came across a strange problem with html anchor tags. I have an anchor tag on the html page and on clicking the 'a' tag it is supposed to give me an alert message. It is working well. But, If I append a new 'a' tag using jquery to the html page and on click of that appended 'a' tag is not working. i was able to give href, target blah blah blah to the appending 'a' tag but.. onlick function is not working. Any thoughts ???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you attach the handler to the onclick event ?

Comment: Some code should be included here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, you typically use the .click() function on a selector to set the click handler.  Note that if multiple items match the selector, multiple items will have the click handler installed.

Here's a trivial code snippet that should do what you want:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function addLink(label, msg) {
            /* Create link element.
               The href="#" makes the link act like a link
               (be highlighted, selectable, etc.).
               The onClick="return false;" keeps the link from
               scrolling the browser to the top of the page.
               The onClick is not interfered with by jQuery's
               .click() . */
            var link = $('<a href="#" onClick="return false;">' + label + '</a>');

            /* Install click handler. */
            function clicked_handler() {
                alert(msg);
            }
            link.click(clicked_handler);

            /* Add the link to the body. */
            $('body').append(link);
        }

        addLink('Link 1', 'You clicked link 1');
        $('body').append('<br/>');
        addLink('Link 2', 'You clicked link 2');

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

I assume that you're adding a click handler to the `<a>` tags by writing `$('a.whatever').click(function() { ... })`, then adding new `<a>` tags to the document.

When you write `$(...).click(...)`, it only adds handlers to the elements that were found by the `$(...)` at the time you added the handler.  It will not apply to any elements you add later.

You're probably looking for jQuery's [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method, which will handle an event for *all* elements that match a selector, no matter when they were created.

For example:

```
$('a.whatever').live('click', function(e) { ... });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply SLaks. Adams Solution worked for me.. Please scroll down to see the answer.
.Live is also a best option to use but..I have so many Jquery scripts in my solution and there is a conflict( still i have to figure out where it is coming from) and it is not recognizing .live as a function and it is throwing errors. The work around solution by Adams is good. Please check that if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$("a").live("click", function(){
 alert("Tadah!");
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Mike. Adams work around solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an event works on stuff that is already on the page. If You add something aferwards You have to bind a new click eventto this new thing or use live, which always should be the second option

so instead of doing

```
$(something).append('<a href="" etc. ');
```

try something like this

```
$('<a></a>').attr('href','some url here').bind('click',function(){}).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply naugtur. Adams Solution worked for me.. Please scroll down to see the answer.